# Pacemaker/corosync timeout before resource transfers

Tags: cluster, timeout, pacemaker, corosync

This seems like a simple question, but one I can't seem to find the answer for despite going over the pacemaker documentation multiple times.

I've got corosync set up with pacemaker to share a virtual IP. All I want to do is to set a timeout value before the backup node takes over the resource. With network outages of <1-2 minutes I'd like pacemaker to just continue on as normal instead of triggering failover, but switch it over if the outage is over a certain number.

There is a timeout for a resource - but this seems to be a the timeout waiting for the resource to start, not for the cluster as a whole.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like [`migration-threshold`](http://www.clusterlabs.org/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1/html/Pacemaker_Explained/s-failure-migration.html) is what you're looking for.

Assumming that you have a resource which is setting `op monitor interval` to 20s:

```
primitive p_foo ocf:heartbeat:foo \
    params ...
    op monitor interval="20s"
```

and you want it doesn't migrate to a new node within 1 minute, so you should set `migration-threshold` to 3:

```
primitive p_foo ocf:heartbeat:foo \
    params ...
    op monitor interval="20s"
    meta target-role="Started" migration-threshold="3"
```

Comment: At the moment I've got corosync with a 'token' of 4 minutes, which seems to do what I want. Assuming that works fine, would this any better?

Comment: @user705142 a cluster that doesn't react to a network outages, for me isn't a cluster.